# SQL: How to properly store data from an outside Excel document source?

Tags: sql-server-2008, excel, normalization

I'm using SQL Server 2008, I'm importing the data using the Import Wizard.

I have data from an excel file like the following...

```
SessionID       Email     SubmitTime      Question1     Question2    Question3 
----------      -----     -----------     ---------     ---------    ----------
54535212        a@b.com   12/21/2011      Yes           No           Yes
54532342        c@d.com   12/22/2011      Yes           Yes          Yes
54535288        e@f.com   12/23/2011      No            No           Yes
54532399        g@h.com   12/24/2011      No            Yes          Yes
```

Now I want to store it in my database so I can easily access the data.  I'm thinking I should make a `Users Table`, `Questions Table`, `Answers Table`, `Submitted Table`.  For my purposes the Submitted Table can become a column for the User’s Table.

```
User
`Email`
`Submitted`
`SessionID`

Question
`Question1`
`Question2`
`Question3`

Answer
`Email`
`Question`
`Answer`
```

How can I populate the Answer table with a query from the Excel document? Or the initial table created from the Excel document on import?  This seems like an easy problem but the solution is for some reason eluding me.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure's a bit screwed up. If you have three columns for `Question1` through `Question3`, then you'd want a `SurveyID` column or something of the sort to identify the unique combinations. Then, your answer table would have `UserID`, `SurveyID`, `Answer1`, `Answer2`, and `Answer3` columns.

If your `Question` table has one `Question` column and a `QuestionID` column (hopefully an `identity` column so it auto-increments, then you'd do something like this to populate the `Answer` table from your `Import` table:

```
insert into answer (userid, questionid, answer)
select
    u.userid,
    q.questionid,
    case
        when q.question = 'Question1' then i.question1
        when q.question = 'Question2' then i.question2
        when q.question = 'Question3' then i.question3
        else null
    end as answer
from
    import i
    inner join users u on
        i.email = u.email
    cross join question q
```

Comment: I'm going through your answer now... I don't know if it matters yet but I have like ~50 questions.  I just only put up 3 for the example sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: @daveomcd - Then I think the `Question` table with two columns: `QuestionID int identity(1,1)` and `Question nvarchar(255)` is for you. In that case, you can use the second SQL statement. You'll just have a pretty long `case`--no getting around that, even with an `unpivot` statement. I'd just write a quick script that generates the `case` clauses.

Comment: good idea with the script thanks for all the advice I'm gonna get on it now thanks!